# Cons in scheme explanation

Tags: scheme, cons

`(cons 1 2)` gives us `(1 . 2)`.

`(cons 3 4)` gives us `(3 . 4)`.

So why does `(cons (cons 1 2) (cons 3 4))` give us `((1 . 2) 3 . 4)`?
Why isn't it `((1 . 2) (3 . 4))`?

Answer (score 5):

Well, it wouldn't be `((1 . 2) (3 . 4))` because that would be a list containing two elements, each a cons pair. I'm guessing what you *meant* was: why isn't it `((1 . 2) . (3 . 4))`?

Well, actually the following two expressions are equivalent:

```
'((1 . 2) . (3 . 4))
'((1 . 2) 3 . 4)
```

This has to do with how Scheme's dotted notation works in tandem with its representation of proper lists. Remember that this:

```
'(1 . (2 . (3 . (4 . ()))))
```

...would simply be printed as this:

```
(1 2 3 4)
```

However, this:

```
'(1 . (2 . (3 . 4)))
```

...would be printed like this:

```
(1 2 3 . 4)
```

Note that Scheme tries to use the simplified list notation as long as it can—it only falls back to explicitly dotting things once it reaches a pair which doesn't have a pair or the empty list as its `cdr` element.

Therefore, in your original example, the second element of that cons pair *is* a pair, so Scheme uses the list notation. That lets it drop the second set of parentheses and the extra dot, yielding the result you encountered.