# How to correctly paste parenthesis in scheme?

Tags: scheme

I don't understand why when I do:

```
(cons (list 1 2) (list 3 4))
```

I get

```
((1 2) 3 4) , but not a ((1 2) (3 4))
```

or

```
         .__4
        / \
       .  3
      / \
     1   2`
```

It's a ternary tree. Left child - binary tree with two leaves. Middle and right child its just a leaves.

I suppose that I have `((1 2) (3 4))` and binary tree with two child's (each of it its binary tree)).

So why [SICP (page 103)](http://web.mit.edu/alexmv/6.037/sicp.pdf#page=103) authors draw a picture where is a ternary tree, not a binary tree?

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: Ah. I think this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/28401857/465378

Comment: But why SICP authors draw a picture with a ternary tree instead of binary? 108 page http://web.mit.edu/alexmv/6.037/sicp.pdf

Comment: Yes, those are equivalent. Likewise, `((1 2) . (3 4))` and `((1 2) 3 4)` are equivalent. You have created the former here. If you want the latter, replace `cons` with `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use this translation:

```
(cons a b)  =   /\           and empty  = .
               a  b
```

First we have the two lists:

```
(list 1 2) = (cons 1 (cons 2 empty)) =   /\
                                         1 /\
                                           2 .

(list 3 4) = (cons 3 (cons 4 empty)) =   /\
                                         3 /\
                                           4 .
```

Using `cons` on the two lists gives:

```
(cons (list 1 2) (list 3 4)) = (cons (cons 1 (cons 2 empty))
                                     (cons 3 (cons 4 empty)))
                             =    / \
                                 /\  /\
                                1 /\ 3 /\
                                  2 .  4 .
```

using list gives:

```
(list (list 1 2) (list 3 4)) = (cons (cons 1 (cons 2 empty))
                                     (cons (cons 3 (cons 4 empty))
                                           empty
                             =     /\___
                                 /\     /\
                                1 /\   /\ .
                                  2 .  3/\
                                        4 .
```

In SICP page 108 they assume that we have a tree represented as lists of trees.
That is: They assume `cons` haven't been used to make the tree.

They use the translation:

```
empty = .

(list a) = |
           a

(list a b) = /\
             a b

(list a b c) =  /|\
                abc
```

Their example

```
(list (list 1 2) 3 4)  =   /|\
                          /\3 4   
                          1 2
```

Since there were no empty lists in the example, we do not use . in the drawing.

In short: The notation in SICP can not be used to draw general data structures built with `cons` and `empty`.

Answer (score 1):

When used to build lists, `(cons x y)` creates a list that has `x` (which can be any type) as its first element and `y` (which must be a list for the result to be a list) as its remaining elements. So `(cons 1 (list 3 4))` gives you `(1 3 4)` and `(cons (list 1 2) (list 3 4))` gives you `((1 2) (3 4))` because `(1 2)` is simply the first element of the list.

If you wanted the result to be `((1 2) (3 4))`, you'd write `(list (list 1 2) (list 3 4))` instead of using `cons`.

The reason that SICP draws a ternary tree is that it represents the trees, such that each list represents a node where each element is a child. So a list with three elements (such as `(1 2 (3 4))`) is a node with three children: two leaves and one subtree with two children (both leaves).